# How to convert a python integer to a integer.Element mod N in Charm-crypto?

Tags: python, charm-crypto

I want to convert a python integer to a integer.Element mod N in Charm-crypto, but I don't know how to do this.
I found the Class of **Conversion** that said its input types can be *bytes, Bytes, int, Integer Element, Modular Integer Element* and output types can be *int, Group element, Integer element, Integer element mod N*, but I can't find a way to convert a int to a Integer element mod N. Anyone knows how to do it?

I want to convert a python integer to a integer.Element mod N in Charm-crypto, but I don't know how to do this.
I found the Class of **Conversion** that said its input types can be *bytes, Bytes, int, Integer Element, Modular Integer Element* and output types can be *int, Group element, Integer element, Integer element mod N*, but I can't find a way to convert a int to a Integer element mod N. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, referred to the website:https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/charm.integer/-/integer/python-integer-function-examples.html
After getting the **integer.Element** by using `Conversion()`, then just modular manually, you will get **integer Element mod N**. It's that simple!

Example:

```
a = 123
bb = Conversion.IP2OS(a, 20)
ele = Conversion.OS2IP(bb, element=True)
aa = ele % mpk['p']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Surprising!**

Motivated by above answer, I found the simplest method to convert a normal int to a integer element mod N.
That is

```
integer(123) % mpk['p']
```